# Can a keyboard event be captured on an aframe entity

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Is it possible to capture a specific keyboard Key event on an AFRAME entity?

I tried via addEventListener on the entity but it seems the event will not be propagated to the entity (with and without wasd-controls).

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('listenonclick', {
    ...
    init: function () {
    ...
        this.el.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
           console.log("onkeydown Button" + event.code);
        });
    ...
    <a-box listenonclick id='box1' ..."></a-box>
```

However, when adding the event to window instead of the entity it will be fired.

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it: Add this code **before** the a-scene

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.listenonkey').forEach(function(obj){
    obj.setAttribute('position', '0 0 0');
  });
});
```

and then

```
  <a-entity class='listenonkey' .... other stuff... </a-entity>
```

Effectively, this solution will add an additional key even handler to the HTML document similar to how aframe does it already, and **onkeydown** moves them.

I haven't found out how to do this more elegantly in the aframe documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the code, works perfect and is very efficient!
In the meantime, I adopted the cursor.js code in order to achieve a similar behaviour to get sure that only the object which points the cursor on will receive the event.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to bind the onkeydown event to an aframe method. That way you can leverage the two way binding more efficiently. Example

```
computed: {
    computed_pos: function () {      
      return `${this.xpos} 1 -2`;
    }
  },
methods: {
     OnKeyDown:function(e){
       if(e.key == "ArrowLeft"){
         this.xpos-=10;
       }
       else if(e.key == "ArrowRight"){
         this.xpos+=10;
       }
       
     }   },   
created: function(){      
       window.addEventListener('keydown', this.OnKeyDown);         
},
```